# What is difference between Altruist and Invester badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

There are two badges:

One is **`Altruist`** which says `First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question`
And another is **`Investor`** which says `First bounty you offered on another person's question`

How are they both different from each other?

Answer (score 1):

Offering a bounty is saying "I'll give reputation the people who answer this question". It then appears on the featured tab. Awarding bounty is saying "OK, you people have answered this question, so I'm giving this much reputation to what I think is the best answer".

More info here: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)